# Ruby could't find the environment variable HOME

Tags: ruby, path

I had some problems running fastlane.

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.129.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:279:in `home': couldn't find HOME
environment -- expanding `~' (ArgumentError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.129.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:279:in `fastlane_user_dir'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.129.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:290:in `persistent_cookie_path'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.129.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:567:in `load_session_from_file'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.129.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:412:in `send_shared_login_request'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.129.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/portal/portal_client.rb:28:in
`send_login_request'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.129.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:771:in `do_login'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.129.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:385:in `login'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.129.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/client.rb:347:in `login'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.129.0/spaceship/lib/spaceship/portal/spaceship.rb:25:in `login'
from ../ruby/ShowCert.rb:31:in `loginPortal'
from ../ruby/ShowCert.rb:46:in `selectTunc'
```

My computer system is `OS 10.13.6`. `HOME=/Users/ergeng` has been added to the environment variable, and `/Users/ergeng` is also displayed when `echo ~`. Php.ini has also been set up, but still not.

So I can't do anything about it now.

```
path = File.expand_path(File.join(Dir.home, ".fastlane"))
```

Comment: `php.ini` has zero impact on Ruby. Are you running this in a regular shell or some other way?

Comment: There's no problem with regular shells. My current approach is to call this ruby script in PHP code.```$exec = "ruby ../ruby/ShowCert.rb" . ' ' . $this->appid . ' ' . $this->password;
        $result = system($exec,$return_status);```

Comment: Maybe your PHP shell environment is mangled and you need to set `HOME` in there. Normally you can pick which environment variables are exported, but `HOME` should be by default.

Comment: Maybe you're right. Anyway, thank you.